# paypal web experience profile list is empty but can't create new profile

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I use the PayPal REST API to create a checkout process in my web shop application. Almost everything works fine but the web experience profile.

So far, I try to check if a profile with a specific name already exists (because the web application created it befor):

```
function get_pp_profiles($pp_token)
{
    $ct = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_URL, PP_PROFILE_ENDPOINT);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_http_headers = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: ' . $pp_token->token_type . ' ' . $pp_token->access_token);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_http_headers);


    if ( $out = curl_exec($ct) )
    {
        $profile_list = json_decode($out);
        curl_close($ct);
        return $profile_list;
    } else
    {
        curl_close($ct);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I then get an empty array (no error). I tried this on the console with "plain" curl (w/o PHP), too - same result.

So, since there is no profile, I'm supposed to set up a new one like this:

```
function set_pp_profile(&$pp_token)
{
    $ct = curl_init();
    $now = time();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_URL, PP_PROFILE_ENDPOINT);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $profile = 
                array(
                      "name" => PP_PROFILE_NAME,
                      "temporary" => true,
                      "presentation" => array(
                                            "brand_name" => "My brand name",
                                            "logo_image" => "http://sonedomain.com/whatever.png",
                                            "locale_code" => "DE"
                                            ),
                      "input_fields" => array(
                                            "no_shipping" => 1,
                                            "address_override" => 1
                                          ),
                      "flow_config" => array(
                                            "landing_page_type" => "billing",
                                            "user_action" => "commit",
                                            "bank_txn_pending_url" => "http://somedomain.com/some_path/"
                                          )
                    );

    $pdata = json_encode($profile, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $curl_http_headers = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: ' . $pp_token->token_type . ' ' . $pp_token->access_token, 'Content-length: ' . strlen($pdata));

    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_http_headers);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pdata);

    if ( $out = curl_exec($ct) )
    {
        echo $out;
        curl_close($ct);
        $profile_object = json_decode($out);
        return $profile_object;
    } else
    {
        curl_close($ct);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this will fail with this return from PayPal:

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"956cbce081ac2","message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/","details":[{"field":"name","issue":"A profile with this name already exists"}]}
```

Does anybody know what's going on there?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Additional test run and info:**

I do know that the profile name must be unique. (But I don't know if I can use a name that had been used before deleting all profiles.)

So I tested as follows:

1. Call the function set_pp_profile(), but changed line 14 as follows:

   "name" => substr(md5("" . time() . rand()), 0, 12),

The result is, as expected, a profile object.

2. Call the function get_pp_profiles(). The function returns an empty array. I put it out with var_dump and will get:

   array(0) { }

My conclusion is that the problem has nothing to do with unique profile names. The PayPal developer docs say the profile will last 3 hours or forever, depending on the "temporary"-Parameter. But this seem not to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem is the PayPal [developer manual](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#web-profile_get-list). The API call

```
GET /v1/payment-experience/web-profiles
```

will return **only** profiles with the parameter "temporary" set to "false". But, if you created profiles with temporary == true, they will exist, too (but hidden)! That's why you can't create a new profile with the same name for 3 hours. Rather poor documentation.

Comment: ha! yes, that's really stupid - and GET /v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/<id> returns a 404, too, for temporary profiles - doesn't make a whole lot of sense imo ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a unique experience profile name each time.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't the problem. Even if I create a fresh, new profile with a unique name (see new example below), I get an empty profile list.